# windows 7 failes to boot afetr installation of ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 7 system. After the installation I can't boot into Windows 7 system, when I select the Windows 7 boot loader in GRUB2, it hangs for seconds and then back to GRUB. I used the `bootinfoscript` to analyze my disk, following is the output:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 63.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048    97,658,879    97,656,832   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3          97,659,196   800,391,167   702,731,972   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5          97,659,198   401,946,299   304,287,102   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda6         401,954,816   597,264,383   195,309,568   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda7         597,266,432   605,076,977     7,810,546  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8         605,079,552   702,734,335    97,654,784  83 Linux
/dev/sda9         702,736,384   800,391,167    97,654,784  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        7F1BDDFE0FA1F135                       ntfs       C:
/dev/sda5        01D07AEB077907E0                       ntfs       F
/dev/sda6        65D918A135513C02                       ntfs       
/dev/sda7        029c2fe2-a482-423f-8e68-4c7819050422   swap       
/dev/sda8        7d83b987-4699-47ac-9537-76049d763138   ext4       
/dev/sda9        1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda8        /home                    ext4       (rw)
/dev/sda9        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda9/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos9'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=UUID=1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-30-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-30-generic-advanced-1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-30-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=UUID=1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-30-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-30-generic-recovery-1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-30-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=UUID=1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos9 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos9  1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1e183f5a-1fe5-4c05-9198-d69a22e358c5
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
```

`

My Windows 7 is originally installed in sda2, while sda1 is "system reserved" generated by win7. Booting with win 7 installation disk and try to repair the boot doesn't work, the repair program can't recognize any boot in C: drive. how can I repair my Windows 7 boot loader now ?

Comment: have you tried bootrepair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Oh yeah, if bootrec can't find any "missing windows" installations you can sometimes fix that from the install disk with `Bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup` and then `ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old` followed by `Bootrec /rebuildbcd`

Comment: try `sudo update-grub` in ubuntu terminal